# How to match start of line and white space in a lookahead expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am sure this is really easy but how do I match

1. match either start of line or whitespace
2. match a-z
3. match either end of line or whitespace

I only want to return item no. 2 so for the following string

```
"one 1.ignore two 2ignore ignore3 three"
```

The expression will return

```
["one","two","three"]
```

Thanks

Comment: For item #1 you would need lookbehind, which is not supported in javascript.

Comment: It just seems like such a straight forward request. But point taken. Maybe someone can find a way around this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You would need lookbehind for a regex that matches these items, which is not supported in javascript. Either you do a manual iteration and extract matching groups (as demonstrated by @Some1.Kill.The.DJ), or you're going to split the string instead of matching:

```
str.split(/\s+(?:\S*?(?![a-z])\S+\s+)*/);
```

This expression does match all whitespaces combined with words that contain at least one character that is not `[a-z]`. However, this regex is complicated and not easy to maintain; also it does yield empty strings sometimes. Better, do something like

```
str.split(/\s+/).filter(RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/^[a-z]+$/));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var str = 'one 1.ignore two 2ignore ignore3 three';
str = str.replace(/\s(?=[a-z])/ig, function(text, p1) {
    return p1 ? p1 : text;
});

var arr = str.match(/([a-z]+)(?=\s|$)/ig);
```

Comment: Just tried your expression in chrome and it returns `["one ", " two ", " three"]`. I don't want the expression to return any of the whitespaces before or after.

Comment: look-behinds are not supported by javascript

Comment: It achieves what I want but I will wait to see if anyone can give me a regular expression to do this.

Comment: Sure, even I am keenly waiting for a single regex based answer though looking at your requirement it appears little difficult to get one.